# Template method with one of the types being itself a template class

Tags: c++, templates

```
class Foo {
public:
   template<typename SignalType, typename ...Arguments>
    void invokeQueued(SignalType<Arguments...>& signal, const detail::identity<Arguments>&... args)
    {
        m_threadSyncQueue.invokeQueued(signal, tag, std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
    }
}
```

This code generates enormous number of errors in all the .cpp files it's included into, starting with

> unrecognizable template declaration/definition

in the first `invoke` parameter. How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use template template parameter.

```
template<template<typename...> class SignalType, typename... Arguments>
```

Comment: Never seen this kind of syntax before. Thank you.